# Send table in pywin32 outlook email

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I use something like the following code to send emails automatically in Python.

How do I make the table look like it was copied from excel into the email (i.e. table formatting)? Currently it treats the html formatted table as text within the body of the email, which is pretty useless.

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

#Parameters
data= [{'A' : 'data', 'B': 2, 'C':1.78},
      {'A' : 'data', 'B': 22, 'C':1.56},]
table = pd.DataFrame(data)

subject = 'email subject'
body = '<html><body>' + table.to_html() + '</body></html>'
recipient = 'email@domain.com'
attachments = []

#Create and send email
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = subject
newMail.Body = body
newMail.To = recipient

for location in attachments:
    newMail.Attachments.Add(Source=location)

newMail.display()
newMail.Send()
```

Sends an email that looks like this when I want it to be an actual table:

```
<html><body><table border="1" class="dataframe"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr style="text-align: left;"> 
      <th>A</th> 
      <th>B</th> 
      <th>C</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td> data</td> 
      <td> 2</td> 
      <td> 1.78</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td> data</td> 
      <td> 22</td> 
      <td> 1.56</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. One line of code needs to change in the original code. Instead of using:

```
newMail.Body = body
```

Do this instead:

```
newMail.HTMLBody = body
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that this helped me out a bunch, thanks. I have it set up to provide a summary of the previous days performance and I attach the raw data for that day. Pretty cool -- this stuff used to take me ages to do in Excel but now it is fully automated with pandas + task scheduler. Amazing

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me alot

Comment: Note that your HTML body text needs to be a valid page. i.e. head and tailed with <HTML><BODY>...</BODY></HTML>